# в onActivityResult нужно обновить объект в базе данных, но ничего не выходит

Tags: android, kotlin, activity, android-room, viewmodel

```
val updatedSubject =
            Subject(id, dayId, name, homework, dayOfWeek, photoPath)
Log.d("Subject", updatedSubject.toString())
viewModel.updateHomework(updatedSubject)
```

Данный код у меня находится в методе **onActivityResult**. В логи выводит обновленный объект правильно, но в БД (**Room**) он не обновляется.
Метод из **ViewModel** этот же самый корректно работает в другом месте, и БД обновляется. Еcть ли идеи, в чем может быть проблема? Или может нужно больше кода для общей картины?

P.S. В **Room DAO** используется аннотация *@Update*, и Primary Key установлен на id моего объекта, и еще раз повторюсь, что в другом месте программы этот метод (**viewModel.updateSubject**) работает как нужно.

Метод из ViewModel:

```
fun updateHomework(subject: Subject) {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            repository.updateHomework(subject)
        }
    }
```

Comment: если в другом месте программы, это работает, то смотреть надо не на этот код, а то что идет перед ним. вы уверены, что он вызывается? возможно, что такого Primary Key в БД нет, и Update не срабатывает ,т.к. ему нужен Insert ?

Comment: Здравствуйте, спасибо за ваш ответ! я уже разобрался,  но забыл сюда отписать) Дело было в том, что я проверял этот апдейт путем скачивания БД моего приложения из памяти устройства и открытия через утилиту DB Browser for SQLite. И там эти апдейты почему-то не отображаются. Но когда я пользуюсь этими данными в самом приложении, они приходят обновленными, такими как нужно. Хотя мне вот непонятно, почему эта утилита конкретно в этом месте не видит обновленные данные.